# Reinstall postfix on ubuntu with installer

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, reinstall

I recently installed postfix but I did something wrong. And so I removed it with `sudo apt-get remove postfix` and removed the `/etc/postfix` folder.

But now I want to install it again but I don't get the installer prompts where I can choose Internet Site and other options. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's because there are still some files in place and dpkg considers the package to be configured.

There are two possible routes you can take to solve this:

1. Now that the package is installed, purge it. Run `sudo apt-get purge postfix`, then re-install and the config dialog should come up.
2. Run `dpkg-reconfigure postfix`

Comment: Thx, that fixed it!